# Ember.js: compute a nested relationship as a model property

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

I currently have three models, Model, Manufacturer, and Device: A Model belongs to a Manufacturer, and a Device belongs to a Model. However, when I list the devices, I'd also like an entry for the manufacturer. I know I can fetch it easily with `model.model.manufacturer.name`, however, I'd like Device to have it's own `manufacturer` property. I have looked into Ember's computed properties, however, I can't seem to find a way to compute the model's manufacturer as the device's property, e.g.:

```
manufacturer: Ember.computed('manufacturer', function () {
  return this.belongsTo('model').manufacturer
})
```

That's what I'm aiming for, but it doesn't work. Is this even possible at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define like this :

```
manufacturer: Ember.computed.alias('model.manufacturer')
```

and if you don't want to set `manufacturer` in `Device` model, so use `oneWay` instead `alias`

Comment: Fantastic, it works flawlessly, thank you very much!